# Convert an object of arrays into an array of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object with arrays, each of which has numbers with double quotes, and I'd like to convert it into an array of arrays without double quotes.

This

```
> Object { CategoryA: Array[182], CategoryB: Array[180],
> CategoryC: Array[182], CategoryD: Array[171],
> CategoryE: Array[182], CategoryF: Array[183] }
```

to

```
Array [ Array[182], Array[182], Array[182], Array[182], Array[182], Array[182] ]
```

I tried `.replace(/"/g, "");` but I'm getting that replace is not a function.

JSON.stringify and JSON.parse didn't help me and a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data2[i] = data[i].replace(/"/g, "");
}
console.log(data2);
```

returns double quotes.

UPDATE

This is how my json looks like

```
{"CategoryA": ["297,239", "277,227", "279,310", "297,766"],
 "CategoryB": ["15,479,207", "14,845,266", "15,454,549"],
 "CategoryC": ["285,648", "295,982", "300,306", "302,508"]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `map` in combination with `Object.keys` like this:

```
var result = Object.keys(yourObject).sort().map(function(key) {
    return yourObject[key].map(function(num) {
        return +num.replace(/,/g, '');
    });
});
```

Please note that the comma `,` in your numbers it's for formatting, not a floating point.

```js
var yourObject = {"CategoryA": ["297,239", "277,227", "279,310", "297,766"],
 "CategoryB": ["15,479,207", "14,845,266", "15,454,549"],
 "CategoryC": ["285,648", "295,982", "300,306", "302,508"]
} ;

var result = Object.keys(yourObject).sort().map(function(key) {
    return yourObject[key].map(function(num) {
      return +num.replace(/,/g, '');
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Thank you @Rayon.

Comment: Right. OP: Be careful `Object.keys` returns the properties of an object in an arbitrary order, so the result of this operation can change over time

Comment: What about _"without double quotes"_ ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but as Rayon said this returns double quotes and changes the order. I would prefer if I could keep CategoryA, CategoryB etc. as well.

Comment: @jimakos17 an object doesn't have an order. Do you mean alphabetical order?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH – How about `ARRAY.map(Number)` ?

Comment: All of my values now are NaN

Comment: @jimakos17 – That is why it is vital to share all the input while posting a question.. Without knowing input values, no one ca test the solution...

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH my values are NaN

Comment: Now is Number { NaN }

Comment: @jimakos17 please share at least a little portion of your object !

Comment: @jimakos17 take a look at the updated answer `,` is just for formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much @IsmailRBOUH

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the keys (to maintain alphabetical order) and apply a replace for changing the comma to point and a casting to number.

```js
var object = { "CategoryA": ["297,239", "277,227", "279,310", "297,766"], "CategoryB": ["15,479,207", "14,845,266", "15,454,549"], "CategoryC": ["285,648", "295,982", "300,306", "302,508"] },
    array=  Object.keys(object).sort().map(function(k) {
        return object[k].map(function (a) {
            return +a.replace(/,/g, '');
        });
    });

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Nina but my values are shown NaN with your reply as well.

Comment: please add your original object.